# How do I convert horizontal split to vertical split and vice-versa in Emacs?

Tags: emacs

How do I convert horizontal split to vertical split and vice-versa in Emacs? Is there a command/recipe for this?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/ToggleWindowSplit

Comment: This is awesome, tu very much for this hint! I was wondering, if we could develop a version that works for an arbitrary number of open windows. The structure of windows builds up a binary tree, where each node holds either VERT or HORZ (i.e. the split mode) and the two window-children, right? Then we could just transpose the first level of that binary tree and keep all lower sub trees. My question is: How can you access the tree structure (if there is one)?

Comment: @mefiX I dont know enough details, sorry :-(

Answer (score 7):

> a version that works for an arbitrary number of open windows

http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/TransposeFrame

https://stackoverflow.com/a/8650787/324105