# Is there a way to retile buffer windows in Emacs?

Tags: emacs

I have two buffer windows open in emacs, arranged vertically. Is there a command that rearranges them horizontally?

Answer (score 8):

The [Transpose Frame](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/TransposeFrame) library provides an excellent set of functionality for manipulating the windows in a frame (any of `transpose-frame`, `rotate-frame-clockwise`, or `rotate-frame-anti-clockwise` would suffice for your particular example).

There are other alternatives, but I find this library fairly comprehensive. See the Wiki page (or the Commentary in the code) for ascii drawings of what each function does.

Answer (score 4):

I use [following snippet taken from Emacs wiki](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/ToggleWindowSplit):

```
(defun toggle-window-split ()
  (interactive)
  (if (= (count-windows) 2)
      (let* ((this-win-buffer (window-buffer))
         (next-win-buffer (window-buffer (next-window)))
         (this-win-edges (window-edges (selected-window)))
         (next-win-edges (window-edges (next-window)))
         (this-win-2nd (not (and (<= (car this-win-edges)
                     (car next-win-edges))
                     (<= (cadr this-win-edges)
                     (cadr next-win-edges)))))
         (splitter
          (if (= (car this-win-edges)
             (car (window-edges (next-window))))
          'split-window-horizontally
        'split-window-vertically)))
    (delete-other-windows)
    (let ((first-win (selected-window)))
      (funcall splitter)
      (if this-win-2nd (other-window 1))
      (set-window-buffer (selected-window) this-win-buffer)
      (set-window-buffer (next-window) next-win-buffer)
      (select-window first-win)
      (if this-win-2nd (other-window 1))))))

(define-key ctl-x-4-map "t" 'toggle-window-split)
```

Just put this into `init.el` and use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>x</kbd> <kbd>4</kbd> <kbd>t</kbd>.

Answer (score 3):

You asked about tiling windows in a frame. Others will answer you directly about that (<kbd>C-x 3</kbd> is a start). But you might also want to know that you can use separate frames and [***tile the frames***](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/Frame_Tiling_Commands) across or down your display.